# Swift: Fastest/Easiest Way to format NSDate()

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a class with this field:

```
let date:String = NSDate().description
```

and the resulting value is this format:

```
"2016-01-10 01:14:20 +0000"
```

But I want the value to simply look like this:

```
"January 1, 2016"
```

What's the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle` as value for the `NSDateFormatter.dateStyle` property:

```
let myDate = NSDate()

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle

let dateAsString = formatter.stringFromDate(myDate)

print(dateAsString)
// January 10, 2016
```

Comment: You may also want to cache the formatter instance if possible, since it's expensive to create.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832768/why-is-allocating-or-initializing-nsdateformatter-considered-expensive

Comment: @ChengYuHsu Thanks for that feedback, that's a good point to think about.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Date {
        static let formatterDateLong: NSDateFormatter = {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var longStyleDate: String { return Date.formatterDateLong.stringFromDate(self) ?? "" }
}

NSDate().longStyleDate  // "January 9, 2016"
```