# NSDateFormatter expense

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, foundation

How expensive creation/modification of DateFormatters is?
Is it cheaper to create 4 slightly different DateFormatters or modify a single DateFormatter?

I vaguely remember that modifying DateFormatters
was as expensive as modifying GL Context (that is: very).

There is a dated discussion on the topic
[Why is allocating or initializing NSDateFormatter considered "expensive"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832768/why-is-allocating-or-initializing-nsdateformatter-considered-expensive)

Comment: It is rather expensive. It's not really about not creating many formatters. You only have to avoid creating them on the fly, e.g. not creating a formatter for every value to be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func testPerformanceExampleUpdateFormat() {
    self.measure {
        (0...1_000).forEach { _ in
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
            let formattedDate1 = df.string(from: Date())
            df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            let formattedDate2 = df.string(from: Date())
        }
    }
}

func testPerformanceExampleNewInstance() {
    self.measure {
        (0...1_000).forEach { _ in
            let df1 = DateFormatter()
            df1.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
            let df2 = DateFormatter()
            df2.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            let formattedDate1 = df1.string(from: Date())
            let formattedDate2 = df2.string(from: Date())
        }
    }
}
```

- Result time when updating a format 1 000 times: 0.0896 s.
- Result time when creating a new instance 1 000 times: 0.138 s.

**How expensive is a type?**

```
func testPerformanceExample() {
    self.measure {
                    (0...1_000).forEach { _ in
            let int = DateFormatter()
        }
    }
}
```

The result time is 0.0017 s. for 1 000 instances of DateFormat

**Let's compare it to other types:**

> 0.000883 s. for 1 000 instances of Int; // let int = 2
>
> 0.000814 s. for 1 000 instances of String; // let str = String("Hello")
>
> 0.00118 s. for 1 000 instances of Date; // let date = Date()
>
> 0.0784 s. for 1 000 instances of UITableViewController; let vc = UITableViewController()
>
> 0.246 s. for 1 000 instances of UITableView; // let tv = UITableView()

Is it expensive?

Comment: This kind of performance tests is really useless. How much is optimized out?

Answer (score 1):

The bad thing about NSDateFormatter is the cost to create a new instance or set format and locale. Actually these actions are one of the most slow operations on iOS SDK and you really must avoid it.
[Read this article to understand more about expensive objects like NSDateFormatter](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2752-25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#reuseobjects)